# 6 Band Resistors, which way should the bands be read

Tags: resistors

I've just bought a bag of random resistors from Maplin, and can't work out which way round the six band ones should be read.

For instance I have one which is either:

> Violet Orange Red Brown Brown Red

or

> Red Brown Brown Red Orange Violet

The red band at either the right or left appears thicker than the others.

Can anybody point me to somewhere with a clear explanation (or provide one themselves) as searching on Google isn't finding me anything lucid.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The folks at [itll.colorado.edu](http://itll.colorado.edu/index.php/electronics_center/resistor_chart/) have a resistor chart that includes how to read 6 Band Resistors. You should start with the thick band. You can always test with a Multimeter too!

[image: Resistor Chart]

Comment: Cheers, I think I may print out this picture to keep next to my work area.

Comment: The diagram appears to have moved to http://itll.colorado.edu/index.php/electronics_center/resistor_chart/

Comment: @littlebirdceo - I've updated it once again, its home is now http://i.stack.imgur.com/CTxAU.png until Stack Exchange goes kaput.

Answer (score 5):

The Gold or Silver band is always set to the right, then you read from left to right. Sometimes there will be no tolerance band -- Simply find the side that has a band closest to a lead and make that the first band."  [1].  Also, usually you'll see one band off by itself, that is the tolerance band.

Comment: Unfortunately if you look at the colours I listed above there are no Gold or Silver bands. Would red being the thickest band (most of the others are the same-ish size) signify it as the temperature band?