# How to find the resistor value using the color codes?

Tags: resistors, colour-coding

The title says it.

Comment: @Rick_2047, I think that we'd answer here. See the Stackexchange FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions

Comment: SE sites were meant to be the source for Google and similar search providers, just as agreed in @O Engenheiro♦'s link.

Comment: -1 from me for such an ill-thought out question., but +1 for Rick_2047 for such a good comment. You should have posted it as an answer.

Comment: @O Engenheiro, "Part of the thinking behind Stack Overflow was for those Google searches to link somewhere useful", but in most of the cases (i.e. when I will put such a comment) google already has the perfect answer.

Comment: Giving him the benefit of the doubt, the OP might be trying to seed this forum with such useful reference info.

Comment: @Rick_2047, @Andrew Kohlsmith - Google won't give me the answers but it gives the links where I can get the answers. I am getting extremely very good answers in this stackoverflow.com site. I know you people are all experts in different technologies and domains. I am sure I will get a very good response here itself. Of course I am not sure whether I will get the good answer in any other site by googling.

Comment: @iRobot, First of all I am no expert, I wouldn't even call myself an medium level person. Did you try searching the exact same sentence which you have posted as the question title? I did, and found this http://www.csgnetwork.com/resistcolcalc.html, I never had to ask anyone again. I know there are some questions which do have answers when you google, but they are moderately hard or bear a personal preference angle (like book suggestions and board suggestions) but asking such a basic question here would be just stupid in my view.

Comment: @Rick_2047 - Of course I can get the answer in other sites also. I think I can get the answer in a text book also. I am a student learning about all these things. And I don't know if there is a rule which says you should post a question after googling and if you don't get any answer elsewhere. if there is such kind of rule then I am sorry.

Comment: @iRobot, The goal is to generate the answers that google would give you on this site. Please ignore Rick_2047

Comment: No personal offense, but that is a stupid goal. I can understand doing this for hard problems, but hey even in the answers nobody gave a comprehensive description of the solution. They just posted a link and was selected as the right answer.

Comment: I understand your point Rick, but this has been discussed in detail on SO and this is the decision they have come to. This site answers all questions, and in theory needs to be the goto place for answer. Google is how we get most of our traffic to grow. How often is someone going to google something that we have in a very specific advanced question, not often (although these are important). Answers like reading resistor color code is what will pull in large numbers of people. Forgive me if you disagree, but you need to take this up on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Rick_2047 - Please see the answer posted by "csadam". I am looking for this kind of answers. Now the answer is very clear. I feel this is not compulsory to post an image but sometimes you don't get an option at that time you may need to select the one which is very close to the answer(Of course it doesn't matter its a reference or not).

Comment: @iRobot, that answer was not there when I posted that comment, you changed you selected answer from that of DarenW to this one. And the fact remains that you were satisfied with a link to another page.

@Kortuk, I didn't know that the chief purpose of this community was to generate traffic. But hey, when the community is this big the majority wins. Who cares about the opinion of a single user.

Comment: @Rick_2047 - Thats what I said. If there is no such kind of answers then I have to select the one which is very close to my expected answer even though it has a link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Comment: @csadmin - It would be helpful if you take and explain wit an example.

Comment: I think the picture speaks for itself :) There are already two examples on it.

Answer (score 8):

There are a zillion websites that cover this.  Some have online interactive tools you can use to read one resistor or learn the art of doing so.  Google "resistor color code"  and maybe add -"free software" to avoid spammy sites.

Here's a basic chart: http://www.azega.com/how-to-read-a-resistor-color-code/

Here's an online tool for practicing, once you think you've got the basics. Comes with sound effects to keep you awake and/or remind you of 1980s style arcade games:

http://www.wisc-online.com/Objects/ViewObject.aspx?ID=DCE1002

These sites could vanish, but others appear.  Quality varies wildly but seek and after perusing several, you'll know what you need to know.

Answer (score 4):

I learned 'em the old-fashioned way:  By having a stack of assorted resistors on my desk and having to look up the code each time I needed one.  Pretty soon, I could recognize a 470 or 10K by sight. (This is what you want, rather than reading digits individually.  Or do you read words one letter at a time?)

Now it is 2010, and color codes are obsolete.  Do not spend time learning them.

Comment: Why are color codes obsoletes?

Comment: They are only used on small, leaded resistors.  Small, leaded resistors are not used in new designs.

Comment: He is correct here, SMD is standard now.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to another question that answers this also: [Resistors with ends of the same colour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/resistors-with-ends-of-the-same-colour/2871#2871)

Answer (score 0):

The basic principle is simple enough.

Each color represents a number. Black: 0, Brown: 1, Red: 2, Orange: 3: Yellow: 4, Green: 5, Blue: 6, Violet: 7, Grey: 8, White: 9.

The normal pattern is.

- 2-3 bands for significant digits of the value (interpreed as an integer, e.g. brown-black-black is 100).
- 1 band for multiplier (10<sup>n</sup> for normal colors 0.1 for gold, 0.01 for silver)
- wider gap
- 1 band for tolerance (this uses it's own meanings for the colors, the most common on modern resistors are probablly 5%: gold 1%: brown and 0.1% violet)
- Some resistors have an extra band for temperature coefficient, but this is rare.

The reality though is that reliablly reading color codes on modern 1% resistors* in the "¼W" or worse "⅛W" body sizes** is very difficult. The bands are often very thin and perception of the colors can easilly be shifted by lighting and the background color, so it's really easy to misread a color band. Further the wider gap is at best only marginally wider and sometimes there doesn't seem to be any distinguishable difference at all in the gaps, so it's easy to end up reading the code backwards.

You can mitigate misreads to some extent by knowing or having a table of likely resistor values. If the value you read isn't in a table of standard resistor values ( http://www.logwell.com/tech/components/resistor_values.html ), then you almost certainly misread it. This doesn't help you with misreading the multiplier though.

* 5% resistors are easier for several reasons, first they usually have the 4-band code giving more space per band. Secondly the last band is gold which basically eliminates the chance of reading the code backwards. Thirdly the background is usually a relatively neutral tan color rather than the blue/green backgrounds typical on metal film resistors.

** Note, body size and power rating are not nessacerally the same, it's common to see 0.6W resistors in the "¼W" body size and 0.4W resistors in the "⅛W" body size