# Resistor values?

Tags: resistors, colour-coding

How can one see what value a resistor is given the colors? For example, what's the value of Red - Orange - Green - Gold?

Comment: This is easily googlabe.

Comment: Lots of reference on the internet.  There is even an [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/992/) about it

Comment: The question has been changed to make this question more broad. Please reconsider your downvotes.

Comment: @LeonHeller that's about the 'background colour'. This is about the colour codes.

Comment: This one, then: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/how-to-find-the-resistor-value-using-the-color-codes?rq=1

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many resistor calculators on the 'net (e.g [this one](http://www.csgnetwork.com/resistcolcalc.html)):

[image: Resistor color codes]

Normally the first two bands are the significant digits and the third is the multiplier, so for example, red/orange/green would indicate 23 * 10^5 = 2.3MΩ

The fourth band indicates tolerance, gold is +- 5%.

There are odd standards out there, including 5 (see asterisk in table above) and 6 band resistors and resistors with the values printed on them. For SMT resistors there are various systems also.

Further reading:
[Electronic color code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code#Resistor_color-coding)