# How do I identify identify if a resistor is 300 or 1k?

Tags: arduino, resistors, resistance

I got an Arduino-compatible board from this [indiegogo campaign](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/9-arduino-compatible-starter-kit-anyone-can-learn-electronics/x/4324656) and the kits come with 10 330-resistors and 10 1k-resistors, but I don't know how do I identify which resistor is which. The [board forums from the campaign's authors](http://forums.borderlesselectronics.org/) are broken (try to register/login), then I cannot ask there.

The resistors have color patterns printed, but I don't know what they mean.

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/6471/2028

Comment: You probably have 330 ohm resistors (not 300). 330 is a common value and are usually marked orange-orange-brown-gold.

Comment: @jippie, you're right. I looked at the indiegogo's campaign and 330, not 300. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question:

**300 Ohm colors are - Orange - black - brown**

**1 K Ohm colors are - Brown - black - red**

Here is the color coding chart to determine the resistor values
 Resistors with four bands are > 1% tolerance resistors. Resistors with 5 band are 1% tolerance resistors.

First three bands determine the value of the resistor.

Fourth band is tolerance of resistor (if only 4 bands on resistor)

[image]

---

[image: Resistor Color Band]

If you deal with resistors frequently and don't want to learn the code, prepare to invest in a [multimeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter) that would tell the approximate value of a resistor.

[image: Multimeter]

Answer (score 2):

A 300Ω resistor would have the color code: orange, black, brown.

A 1kΩ resistor has the color code: brown, black, red.

The fourth band, if present, is the tolerance. (Silver = ±10%, Gold = ±5%, Red = ±2%)

This is assuming you have carbon composition resistors.