# What is the value of these resistors?

Tags: resistors

Two resistors in a Bosch AL 1115 CV battery charger 127V burned up yesterday, and I am trying to figure out the correct value to replace them.

I have found in the internet this photo where I suppose that these resistors are of the same value of that burned in my board:

[image]

This is a image of a similar board that I found on the internet:

https://radikal.ru/fp/b0963f27083043e185cba4facee7ad1c

This is a photo of my real board, that was burnt:

[image]

In that two resistors that burnt, in the similar board figure, I see the colors:

```
brown, white, red, red, black.
```

What is the value of this resistor?

I have learned that in 5 bands resistors, the first, second and third band are the value, the fourth id the multiplier and the fifth is the tolerance.

Black does not exist as a tolerance and in some five band resistors the third band is the multiplier, and not the fourth.

How do J know when take into account the third band as multiplier or the fourth band as multiplier?

What is the real value of the resistors in the figure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read these blasted five-band resistors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/348599/how-do-i-read-these-blasted-five-band-resistors)

Comment: Fourth band looks to be silver rather than white.  That should make things easier for you to figure out.

Comment: In addition to the band looking silver instead of white, are those really two red bands, or is one of them orange?

Comment: I add a full image of the board where u could compare the orange color that is hard to see because the low resolution of the image.

Comment: Taking in consideration that the fourth band are silver, so this resistor are something around 1.22 Ohm? Of fact, is few probably that are a white multiplier because white multiplier have a value of 9 zeroes and it is impracticable. What do you think?

Comment: Resistors in the gigaohm range are unlikely to be in that form factor; you need to make them out of special low-leakage materials and use very wide lead spacing so that leakage across the board doesn't mess up the resistance. And you would probably want a special board material and maybe some kind of conformal coating or even potting to limit surface leakage. So yes, I think it's unlikely the multiplier band is white.

Comment: So that is a 0.22 Ohms resistor?

Comment: Some other hint, guys?