# power board regulator/resistors

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

[image: resistor values][image: here is a picture of the power regulator board]

could someone please tell me what the value of the three resistors  in circle

(R1) 1 orange,orange black,gold
red,red,black,gold and the same for the third

(R2/R3)second the grey resistor

(R28)  brown,black,silver,gold,black

(R30)not sure if its pink,purple or brown , red,gold ?

the rest i have managed  to get the values

i cant seem to find hem anywhere 
thanks

Comment: Also [Resistors with ends of the same colour](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/resistors-with-ends-of-the-same-colour/2871#2871)

Answer (score 0):

See this handy table from Digikey:

[image]

R30 (39?) 1K 5%

R28 0.01 ohm 5%

R2/R3 22 ohms 5%

Comment: not seen these for a while as they are now smaller thanks bin out of the game for a while were bigger when i use to be at school/collage